# Providing the Custom Name to both Key and Value Pairs of an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a **table** named **questions** in the following form:

**Table Name: questions**

```
     qn_id    |          question                          |
   ---------------------------------------------------------------

        19    | What is your rating on your Team Work?

        20    | What is your rating on your Skills?

        21    | What is your rating on your Personal Quality?
```

I have another table named **rating** as shown below:

**Table Name:** **rating**

```
id  | employee_id | question_id | self_score  | supervisor_score
-----------------------------------------------------------------

1   |  205        |  19         |    4        |     3
2   |  205        |  20         |    5        |     4
3   |  205        |  21         |    4        |     5
```

**Note:** There are two people involved in providing the score. One is **supervisee** and another is **supervisor**.

The **score** provided by the **supervisee** is kept in the column named **self_score**. In the table, **employee_id** is the **id** of the **supervisee**. **Supervisor** also gives the **rating** to the **supervisee** for the same **question** as shown aboove in the table.

I have generated the **data** from the database as an **Array** which is shown below:

```
$params = Array
                (
                [selfscore_19]       => 4
                [supervisorscore_19] => 3

                [selfscore_20]       => 5
                [supervisorscore_20] => 4

                [selfscore_21]       => 4
                [supervisorscore_21] => 5
                )
```

Note: In the key named **[selfscore_19]** **,** **selfscore_** is the string and **19** is the question id.

**Questions** are same for both - '**self**' and '**supervisor**'.

So I have appended the strings named '**selfscore**' and '**supervisorscore**' with the **question_id**.

In the array shown below, key is: **[selfscore_19]** which has been appended with the **question_id** i.e **19** and 
the value is **score** provided by '**self**' which is **4**.

And other data follows similar pattern.

**Attempt:**

The code below shows the attempt done by me so far:

*Note: I have only shown the main part of the method.*

```
    foreach($params as $key => $value){
        $exp_key = explode('_', $key);
        if($exp_key[0]=='selfscore'){
            $arr_result[] = $value;
        } 
    }

    foreach($params as $key => $value){
        $exp_key = explode('_', $key);
        if($exp_key[0]=='supervisorscore'){
            $arr_result[] = $value;

        }
    }

    if(isset($arr_result)){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr_result);
        echo '<pre>';
    }
```

This is the output of the above code:

**Current Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4

    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

**Now I want to tranform the Current Output in the form of following Output. 
Although I have already researched about this case, but I am finding it a bit tricky.
What modification should I do to achieve the required output?
Suggestions are highly appreciated.**

**Required Output:**

```
$score['self_score']=array(
            array('question_id'=>19,'score'=>4)
            array('question_id'=>20,'score'=>5)
            array('question_id'=>21,'score'=>4)
        );

$score['supervisor_score']=array(
            array('question_id'=>19,'score'=>3),
            array('question_id'=>20,'score'=>4)
            array('question_id'=>21,'score'=>5)
        );
```

Comment: How are you creating the $params array?  You should never end up with an array like that to begin with.

Comment: Any chance that you are querying with pdo?  There are far too many indirect steps in your multi-dim array preparation.  Are you open to PDO solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a single loop. Use the first part of `$exp_key` as the key of the resulting array, and the second part as the value of the `question_id` key of the sub-array.

```
foreach ($arr_result as $key => $value) {
    $exp_key = explode("_", $key);
    $score[$exp_key[0]][] = array("question_id" => $exp_key[1], "score" => $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll recommend that you use a `UNION` to join two simple queries so that your initial resultset is very close to what you want (close enough to simply iterate and/or modify it).

SQL: ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/292736/4))

```
(SELECT 'group' AS 'self_score', question_id, self_score
FROM rating
WHERE employee_id = 205
ORDER BY id)
UNION
(SELECT 'supervisor_score', question_id, supervisor_score
FROM rating
WHERE employee_id = 205
ORDER BY id)
```

Resultset:

```
       group      |  question_id  |  self_score
------------------|---------------|------------
    self_score    |      19       |      4
    self_score    |      20       |      4
    self_score    |      21       |      5
supervisor_score  |      19       |      3
supervisor_score  |      20       |      4
supervisor_score  |      21       |      5
```

If you are open to a PDO solution, [fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP) will come in pretty handy.